# Using New and Delete with Dynamic pointer array of type structure

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, memory, segmentation-fault

I am currently using the following code:

```
student_info **array;
array = new student_info*[size];
for(int i = 0; i < 19; i++)
{
    array[i] = new student_info[size];
}
for(int i = 0; i < 19; i++)
{
    delete[] array[i];
}
delete[] array;
```

"student_info" is the structure, "array" is the pointer array of the type structure.

The code compiles; however, when I attempt to access the items inside the array results in the segfault core dump.

Accessing code:

```
in_s >> array[i] -> first;
```

This code is also inside the for loop with the new. Assume in_s is an instream object and first is part of the structure.

Which part of my memory allocation was wrong? The "size" variable is 19, but I am unsure if "size" is what I should use in the inner array memory allocation.

Thanks!

Comment: "when I attempting to access the items inside the array results in the segfault core dump." How do you access them? Show the relevant code.

Comment: updated to show a scenario which causes the segfault

Comment: Based on the code shown, you're allocating the array and its members and then deleting them immediately afterwards. Presumably you then go on to use the deleted array somewhere else? Or is there a chance you've left something out?

Comment: @JonathanPotter yes my bad for not showing the part where I access the items. I've updated it to show what example of code would be directly following the new within the first for loop.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to go through the [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) on what and how you can ask here. It's especially important to post a [mcve].

Comment: Ever heard of `std::vector`?

Comment: @NickyC I'll admit I have not. For the purpose of this assignment I believe I have to use arrays though?

Comment: Hard to say for sure, but the general trend at school is to the no `vector` side of things. You sure you need an array of pointers to more arrays? From the way it appears you want to use `array`, `student_info *array;`, `array = new student_info[size];` and `in_s >> array[i].first;`, no first loop. No second loop.